# How many polynomial Morse functions on the sphere?

Tags: gn.general-topology, co.combinatorics, polynomials

Let $f$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ in $n$ variables. Restricted to the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$, it might or might not be a Morse function.

If $f$ is a Morse function of degree $1$, you get everyone's favorite Morse function on the sphere, with two critical points, corresponding to the minimal CW decomposition.

If $f$ is a Morse function of degree $2$, you get everyone's second-favorite Morse function, corresponding to the minimal regular CW decomposition with two points, two lines, two faces, and so on.

If $f$ has degree $d\geq 3$, there are a lot more possibilities. How many?

The space of degree $d$ homogeneous polynomials in $n$ variables can be identified with $\mathbb R^N$ where $N={\left( \begin{array}{c}n+d-1 \\ n-1\end{array}\right)}$. The ones that are Morse functions form an open subset.

> About how many connected components does this open subset have for large $d$ and/or $n$?

Comment: If you consider the case $n=2$, I believe the precise answer to your question should be known for all $d$. V.I. Arnol'd was interested in such type of questions, originally in the case when you replace $S^1$ by $\mathbb R^1$ and homogeneous polynomials by inhomogeneous. Probably one should chase the references to Arnold's article :
 http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=4470&option_lang=rus

You might also want to have a look on the article of Barannikov "On the space of real polynomials without multiple critical values"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've been trying to answer this question for several years and it turned out to be really  hard, even for the $2$-sphere.   Below I will discuss this case.

First of all  one should  ask   what  is the number $m(k)$ of topological types  of (stable) Morse functions on $S^2$  with  precisely $k$ saddle points. (such a function has $2k+2$ critical points.)  I showed that the generating series

$$ x(t) := \sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{m(k)}{(2k+1)!} t^{2k+1}, $$

is the inverse  of an elliptic integral; see  [this paper](http://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Morse-count.pdf).  More precisely $x(t)$ is the inverse of the function

$$ x\mapsto t(x)=\int_0^x \frac{ds}{\sqrt{s^4/4-s^2-2sx+1}} ds. $$

This fact   leads to a positive answer to a [question of V.I. Arnold](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/presentation.phtml?option_lang=eng&presentid=189)   who conjectured that
$$\log m(k)\sim 2k\log k $$

as $k\to \infty $. I refer you to  [this paper](http://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/statistics.pdf) for details.   This shows that $m(k)$ grows rather fast as $k\to \infty$.

Any   polynomial $P$ of degree $d$ in $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ on $\bR^n$   can  be uniquely decomposed  as a sum

$$ P= \sum_{0\leq j+2k\leq d} r^{2k} H_{j}, \;\; r^2= (x_1^2+\cdots +x_n^2), $$

where $H_{j}$ is a darmonic polynomial of degree  $j$.      On $\bR^3$ the space of degree $d$ hormonic polynomials has dimension  $2d+1$.   If we denote by $U_d$ the subspace of $C^\infty(S^2)$ consisting of the restrictions to $S^2$   of the  polynomials of degree $\leq d$  we deduce that

$$\dim U_d=\sum_{0\leq k\leq d} (2k+1)=(d+1)^2. $$

Denote by $K_d$ the expected number of critical points of a random function in $U_d$. I showed  that

$$ K_d\sim C\dim U_d\sim Cd^2 $$

as $d\to \infty$ where $C$  is a certain explicit constant; see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.5085) and [this paper](http://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/CritSetStat.pdf).

It turns out that the   number of critical points of a random function in $U_d$ is     highly concentrated around its mean $K_d$, i.e., the probability that the number of critical points of a random function  in $U_d$ is far from the mean  $K_d$ is extremely small as $d\to\infty$.  In more precise technical terms, the variance of the  (random) number of critical points of a (random) function in $U_d$  has the same size  as $K_d$, which makes the standard deviation  of size $\sqrt{K_d}$, much, much smaller than $K_d$ for $d$ large.

I personally believe, based on some empirical evidence,   that the mean  is close to the  maximum number of critical points    in the sense  that if  we denote by $\mu_d$ the maximum number of critical points of a  Morse function in $U_d$, then $\mu_d \sim C'' d^2$ as $d\to\infty$.

My guess is that the number of topological types of functions in $U_d$  as $d\to \infty$ is roughly

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{K_d/2} m(k), $$

where I recall that $m(k)$ denotes the number of topological types  of Morse functions with $k$ saddle points, i.e., $2k+2$ critical points.

Comment: Do you know any upper or lower bounds, even very bad ones?

Comment: The brief answer is I don't have an explicit upper bound on the top of my head but I think I know  methods of producing a (really bad) upper bound valid  for all polynomials $p\in U_d$  situated outside a semialgebraic subset of $U_d$ of codimension $\geq 1$. This is  what many  real algebraic geometers do for a living.  I recommend a book  by Basu, Pollack and Roy for inspiration http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted1.html