# Examples of Morse functions on unit tangent bundle of the sphere $T^1(S^2)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

In a sense, calculus is all about the study of critical points of functions on flat space $\mathbb{R}^N$ (e.g. [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805390219)).  Let's try a different venue, the unit tangent bundle of the sphere. 
$$ T^1(S^2) = \big\{ (x,\vec{v}): x \in S^2,\, \vec{v} \in T_x(S^2),\, \big|\big|\,\vec{v}\,\big|\big|=1 \big\} $$

And there are other example of circle bundles over the sphere, such as tensor products of this bundle with itself.  I was able to obtain on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60522/the-circle-bundle-of-s2-and-real-projective-space?noredirect=1&lq=1) a rather general result: cohomology of circle bundles can be found via the Gysin exact sequence. Can obtain this result via Morse theory?

- $H^0\big( T^1(S^2) \big) \simeq \mathbb{Z} $
- $H^1\big( T^1(S^2) \big) \simeq 0 $
- $H^2\big( T^1(S^2) \big) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $
- $H^3\big( T^1(S^2) \big) \simeq \mathbb{Z} $

I post this question here because I know explicit Morse functions always exist but can be difficult to find.  And I'm trying to work out the critical points and visualize the Morse flow.

And perhaps I should clarify what I mean by "explicit".  I believe the unit tangent bundle could be given the structure of a variety.  Looking at our construction, we could try to embed

$$  T^1(S^2) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3$$

I don't think his is quite the "universal bundle" construction, but it's something.  And we could write down the constraints:

- $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = 1$
- $v_1^2 + v_2^2 + v_3^2 = 1$
- $\vec{v} \in T_x(S^2) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ which could be a hyperplane in 3-space.
- $\langle x, v \rangle = x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + x_3 v_3 = 0$ this shows that $\vec{x} \perp \vec{v} $ and that $\vec{v}$ is tangent to $S^2$.

And if we pin down all the relations we obtain the structure of an algebraic variety.  Therefore, could it be possible to write down **polynomial** morse functions of this kind of space?  And work out the critical points?

- [How many polynomial Morse functions on the sphere?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125944/how-many-polynomial-morse-functions-on-the-sphere)
- [cohomology module of unit tangent vector bundles over spheres](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228458/cohomology-module-of-unit-tangent-vector-bundles-over-spheres)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gysin_homomorphism

Even a derivation of the Gysian homomorphism via Morse theory could be interesting.  Certainly I've never seen it.

---

We could try to build Morse functions of out of polynomials in $x$ and $v$. Does the set Morse functions of given degree form a vector space?

Comment: Is not this just $S^3$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე $\mathbb{R}P^3$ ?

Comment: You are right, it is $SO(3)$

Comment: Isn't $x_1+2v_2$ a Morse function? I haven't done the computation, but I'd say it has exactly $4$ critical points, namely $(\pm1,0,0;0,\pm1,0)$, of index $0,1,2,3$

Comment: Even for reasonable choice of a section, a straightforward computation of the critical points could go awry.  A natural-looking function might might be Morse due to a technicality.  Non-generic behavior or the level sets is to be expected.

Comment: Most linear functions will be Morse.  Given that the unit tangent bundle is quadratic, this is a very reasonable Morse-theory setup.

Answer (score 5):

To expand the comment: the function $f(x,v):=x_1+2v_2$ is a Morse function on $M:=T^1 S^2$, in your coordinates $(x,v)$. Denoting $(e_j)_{1\le j\le3}$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, it is easy to see that the only critical points $ p:=(  x,v)\in M$ of $f$ are $p_0:=(-e_1,-e_2)$, $p_1:=(e_1,-e_2)$, $p_2:=(-e_1,e_2)$, and $p_3:=(e_1,e_2)$, and   that $\text{ind}(p_k)=k$. This is more or less evident from geometrical considerations. To make a formal computation, define for $q:=(q_1,q_2,q_3)$ in a nbd of $0\in\mathbb{R}^3$ the skew simmetric matrix
$$Q=Q_q:=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-q_{{3}}&q_{{2}}\\  q_{
{3}}&0&-q_{{1}}\\ -q_{{2}}&q_{{1}}&0\end {array}
 \right], $$
and consider a local chart at $p$ of the form $(q_1,q_2,q_3)\mapsto (e^Qx,e^Qv)$. In this chart the function $f$ reads $\tilde f(q)=[e^Qx]_1+2[e^Qv]_2$; since $e^Q=I+Q+Q^2/2+o(Q^2)$ at $Q=0$, by easy computations this gives the second order expansion at $q=(0,0,0)$; precisely
$$\nabla \tilde f(0)= (-2v_3 ,\ x_3 ,\  2v_1-x_2)  $$
$$\text{Hess }\tilde f(0):=\ \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} -4\,v_{{2}}&2\,v_{{1}}+x_{{2}}&x_{{3}}
\\  2\,v_{{1}}+x_{{2}}&-2\,x_{{1}}&2\,v_{{3}}
\\  x_{{3}}&2\,v_{{3}}&-4\,v_{{2}}-2\,x_{{1}}
\end {array} \right] \ .$$
So if $\nabla\tilde f(0)=0$ then $x_3=v_3=0$ and $x_2=2v_1$; since $x\cdot v=0$ also $|v_1|=|x_2|$, so that $v_1=x_2=0$ and since $\|x\|=\|v\|=1$ we also get $x_1=\pm1$, and $v_2=\pm1$, that is $p$ is one of $p_0,\dots, p_3$. For each of these values $\text{Hess }\tilde f(0)$ is a diagonal matrix with respectively $0,\dots,3$ negative elements, ending the computation.

Comment: This looks nice.  I didn't pick a complicated space either $T^1 S^2 \simeq SO(3)$ is very natural.  There are many natural situations where $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ won't be quite Morse.  Or we may not get to choose $f$ at all.